# How to convert UPPERCASE text to Title Case using CSS

Tags: php, css

If you're reading this you probably noticed that the CSS property `text-transform:capitalize;` does not convert THIS into This. Instead the, non-initial characters remain capitalized, so the transformation has no effect in this case. So how can we achieve this result?

I've seen this asked often and most answers are quick to promote using javascript to accomplish this. This will work, but it is unnecessary if you are writing or customizing a template/theme for a PHP CMS like Wordpress, Drupal, or Joomla.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The bad news is that there is no such thing as `text-transform : title-case` which would guarantee the result to be title cased. The good news is that there IS a way to do it, which doesn't require javascript (as is often suggested for this situation). If you are writing a theme for a CMS you can use strtolower() and [`ucwords()`](https://www.php.net/ucwords) to convert the relevant text to title case.

BEFORE (THIS DOESN'T WORK):

```
<style>
.title-case{ text-transform:capitalize; }
</style>
<span class="title-case">ORIGINAL TEXT</span>
```

AFTER:

```
<?php echo ucwords( strtolower('ORIGINAL TEXT') ); ?>
```

If you are writing a theme, you'll probably be working with variables instead of text strings, but the function and the concept work the same way. Here's an example using the native Wordpress function [get_the_title()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title) to return the page title as a variable:

```
<?php
$title = get_the_title();
$title = strtolower($title);
$title = ucwords($title); 
<h1>
<?php echo $title;
</h1> 
?>
```

Hope this helps someone. Happy coding.

Comment: `ucwords` on its own is not enough, you'll also have to turn the string to lower case first. `ucwords(strtolower('ORIGINAL TEXT'));`

Answer (score 19):

To some degree you can achieve this with CSS using the pseudo class ::first-letter and should work all the way back to IE 5.5 :-(

NOTE: this is very dependent on your html structure, and will not work in all cases, but can be useful from time to time. Hit "run code snippet" to the see the result below.

```css
.progTitle {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}

.progTitle::first-letter {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<p class="progTitle">THIS IS SOME TEST TEXT IN UPPERCASE THAT WILL WORK. </p>
<p class="progTitle">this is some test text in lowercase that will work. </p>
<p class="progTitle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> THIS WILL NOT WORK </p>
```

Comment: This might get you proper capitalization for the first sentence of the text, but does not achieve 'title case' which would be 'This is some Test Text in Uppercase that will Work" (whether or not to capitalize 'some' is a matter of taste/judgement')

Comment: Hi @Gus you are correct, this answer will give you sentence case not title case. There was no mention in the original question as to which was preferred, hence why I added the caveats to the original answer. This is probably less resource dependent than a JS solution, but is not suitable for all use-cases.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to have a class or element for the particular text and use this CSS rule:

```
.my_text {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}


<p class="my_text">hello stackoverflow!!</p>

 
h1 {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}


<h1>hello stackoverflow!!</h1>
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is a working example in a Joomla 1.5.22 website running Virtuemart 1. The purpose is to take a string which is originally UPPERCASE, and convert it to Proper Case.

UPPERCASE:

```
<?php echo $list[$i]->name; ?>
```

Proper Case:

```
<?php echo ucwords( strtolower($list[$i]->name) ); ?>
```

Comment: Not a CSS solution... This question is asking about CSS.

Answer (score -5):

This can be achieved with one simple rule:

```
text-transform: capitalize;
```

Comment: Please present your use-case scenario. I've found this to work quite easily.

Comment: @EmmanuelBuckshi in the method you suggest, the second rule will overwrite the first, not build on each other as you imply. You say it works for you - can you present your working use case?

Comment: You're right -> the first rule is unnecessary. Overall, however, the second rule (by itself) should lead to the result desired by the OP (it "works").

Comment: In any case, my answer is the only one that really solves the problem without using php. The accepted answer is wrong, because it states that there is no css rule for "title case"; there most definitely is, and my answer clearly displays it.

Comment: This will only convert the first letter of each word to uppercase if its lowercase, it won't convert uppercase to lower for subsequent letters. Hence the requirement in other answers to convert to lower case first

Comment: @EmmanuelBuckshi Title case normally means something like "The Lord of the Rings" where the first word and significant words are capitalized, and small words are not. Capitalize capitalizes all words regardless of significance. i.e. "Lord Of The Rings" Also as Morveael notes capitalize leaves letters other than the first letter untouched. To handle true title case, CSS would need to know what words were significant. Consider: "The One" vs "Life one Canoli at a Time"... how does one know how to treat the word 'one'? This is probably why there's no `text-transform:title-case`

Comment: @Gus That's an well expressed discrepancy..  sounds interesting to try and solve this

Answer (score -6):

You just write `text-transform: none;`

Comment: That would not work if your input text is uppercase.

Comment: Also title case doesn't mean no transform. Title case means the first letter of each word in uppercase, rest lower. OP is looking for `capitalize`.

Comment: @EduardLuca that's not what title case means either: http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/capital_letters_title_case.htm (I agree that this answer won't work however)

Comment: @Gus yeah, there's no way to do that in CSS, so what I said is the closest to what's possible.