# Can I make an ALL UPPER CASED string in a button Proper Cased

Tags: html, css

I really would like SEARCH to become Search and CLEAR ALL to become Clear All

This CSS doesn't work (grabbed it from [CSS text-transform capitalize on all caps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471157/css-text-transform-capitalize-on-all-caps)).

```css
.common-search-footer {
  display: flex;
  background: #ededed;
  font-size: small;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 100%;
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

.common-search-footer,
.common-search-footer:first-line {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<mat-card-footer class="common-search-footer">
  <button mat-button type="submit" id="searchButton">
          <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i> SEARCH</button>
  <button mat-button class="red" type="button" id="clearButton">
          <i class="fa fa-times"></i> CLEAR ALL</button>
</mat-card-footer>
```

Comment: So the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54711164/14104 in the link you posted did not work?

Comment: @epascarello - it did not.  What I was missing was the button > span combo.  I figured that the link I posted was close but didn't realize that extra steps to get there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to set the [`text-transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform) to the `<button>` itself:

```css
.common-search-footer {
    display: flex;
    background: #ededed;
    font-size: small;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); 
    width: 100%;
}

.common-search-footer > button {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}

.common-search-footer > button:first-line {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<mat-card-footer class="common-search-footer">
  <button mat-button type="submit" id="searchButton">
    <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i> SEARCH</button>
  <button mat-button class="red" type="button" id="clearButton">
    <i class="fa fa-times"></i> CLEAR ALL</button>
</mat-card-footer>
```

---

Note that due to [`:first-line`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line), this will only work if you content does not exceeds a single line.

Since `capitalize` does not work on upper cased text, we first apply `text-transform: lowercase` to ensures we `lowercase` the text. Then we *overwrite* it with `text-transform: capitalize` on the `:first-line`.

- [CSS text-transform capitalize on all caps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471157/css-text-transform-capitalize-on-all-caps)
- [First lowercase the text then capitalize it. Is it possible with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280015/first-lowercase-the-text-then-capitalize-it-is-it-possible-with-css)
- [How to convert UPPERCASE text to Title Case using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793666/how-to-convert-uppercase-text-to-title-case-using-css)

Comment: It looks like you're using `:first-line` as a pseudo-override. That's still not clear in your answer as there's no requirement to restrict transformation to the first line.

Comment: I see what's going on here. It is `text-transform: capitalize;` that does the work we need but it wont capitalize text that is already caps. Hence making it lowercase first then using a pseudo to override it. Smart. Would be nice if this (or a better explanation) was given in your answer.

Comment: I've edited my answer with your suggestions. Hope this makes it more clear. Since I'm not a native english speaker, feel free to improve the structure/spelling.

Comment: @0stone0 - Thank you for your answer.  This is what I needed!  I did have to modify the last css to be this: .common-search-footer > button > span:first-line - as Angular Material seems to add SPAN tags inside of the button.  After that it worked like a charm!